# Wordpress php SELECT probable syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

So , I am getting from a form throw post this field

```
$OrderLNumber = $_POST['OrderLNumber'];
```

and it works fine as I checked it with an Echo. 
Then I connect my db with the classic :

```
// Database Connection String
                $con = mysql_connect($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password);
                if (!$con)
                {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                }

                mysql_select_db($db_database, $con);
```

Which works because the page is actually loading. When I mess this side of the code the page does not load. 
 
And then I am actually trying to get a SELECT FROM WHERE and print the resulted rows. I do not know what kind of mistake I have made in this part of the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM OrderStatus WHERE OrderLineNumber = $OrderLNumber "; 
                $result = mysql_query($con,$sql); 
                if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {  

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
                        echo 'OrderLineNumber: ' .$row['OrderLineNumber'];  
                        echo 'Date Started: ' .$row['DateStarted'];  
                        echo 'Status: '.$row['Status'];  

                        }  

                    }
```

I don't understand whether it's a syntax error , a server side error or a logic error. 
Thank you very much in advance.

**UPDATE (should this work ?)**

```
<?php

if($_POST['submit']) {

                    $OrderLNumber = $_POST['OrderLNumber'];
                    $results = $wpdb->get_results(  
                                "
                                SELECT * FROM $wpdb->OrderStatus WHERE OrderLineNumber = $OrderLNumber
                                "
                                );
                    foreach ($results as $result)
                    {
                        echo $result;
                    }
                        }
        else { 


        ?>
```

Comment: You're prone to SQL injection - stop using `mysql_` as it's been deprecated. Use `mysqli_` instead or PDO.

Comment: @Edward This is WordPress, so WPDB is the answer.

Comment: **WARNING**: You've created a dangerous [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/) by putting `$_GET` data directly in your query. **NEVER** do this. Instead, use the WordPress [prepared statements feature](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) to properly escape all data parameters. **DO NOT** use `mysql_query` for WordPress code, it's been removed from PHP 7 because it's so dangerous.

Comment: appreciate the help m8 . Would this solve the problem ?

Comment: So @tadman . What exactly should I do  ?

Comment: Use WPDB for any and all database interaction. WordPress already knows how to connect to your database and run queries through that interface. I've linked to the documentation in my first comment.

Comment: @tadman I updated with wpdb . Is that correct use ?

Comment: Getting a lot closer, but pay very careful attention when composing queries and do not put in things like `$OrderNumber`, that creates a SQL injection problem. Instead put in `?` and use the binding feature to add the data when executing.

Comment: but if that is a safety issue shouldn't this be working ? I am getting a white page here :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<?php

    if($_POST['submit']) {

        global $wpdb;

        $OrderLNumber = $_POST['OrderLNumber'];

        $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}OrderStatus WHERE OrderLineNumber = $OrderLNumber");

        foreach ($results as $result)
        {
        echo $result;
        }
    }
?>
```